# How to close TextDocument in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing vscode extension.

I opened a TextDocument with `vscode.window.showTextDocument`, and want to close it later. But I can't find api to close it. Finally I found [this commit](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/d625b55e9ec33f95d2fe1dd7a4b7cb50abb4772c#diff-4654cd1aa2a333bc6cc7ca0d19fdfb6e), it removed `closeTextDocument`. What should I do now?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. The only way I managed to do it is via `workbench.action.closeActiveEditor`, as recommended by the inline documentation for `TextEditor.hide`.

It's hackish - basically show the document in the editor, then close the active editor:

```ts
vscode.window.showTextDocument(entry.uri, {preview: true, preserveFocus: false})
    .then(() => {
        return vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.closeActiveEditor');
    });
```

Comment: `showTextDocument()` returns a `Thenable<TextEditor>` so why you need to invoke a command instead of using the value from the promise? i.e. `then((textEditor) => textEditor.hide())`

Comment: @Sebastian Because `textEditor.hide` is deprecated. According to VSCode docs:
> Use the command `workbench.action.closeActiveEditor` instead. This method shows unexpected behavior and will be removed in the next major update.

Comment: can you prevent or programmatically answer the question of "should I save the changes?"

Answer (score 6):

Since VSCode v1.67 you can use `TabGroups` to find and close the document of your liking.

E.g. like this (in **TypeScript**):

```js
import * as vscode from "vscode";

export async function closeFileIfOpen(file:vscode.Uri) : Promise<void> {
    const tabs: vscode.Tab[] = vscode.window.tabGroups.all.map(tg => tg.tabs).flat();
    const index = tabs.findIndex(tab => tab.input instanceof vscode.TabInputText && tab.input.uri.path === file.path);
    if (index !== -1) {
        await vscode.window.tabGroups.close(tabs[index]);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```js
const myFile = vscode.Uri.file('c:\some\random\file.txt');
await closeFileIfOpen(myFile);
```

Ref: originally inspired by [this answer from ct_jdr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73733833/1716283).